# Low-overhead type conversion of 2D arrays between Rust and C

Tags: arrays, rust, ffi

I am writing a shared library in Rust that will expose a C compatible interface. One of the function takes a 2D array of chars, `char **obj_ptr`, performs some simple computations on the array and returns to the caller.

Since this function will be called very often, all the operation needs to be fast. The obvious way of converting the array to a slice of slice representation would need iterating through all the elements. Is there a low-overhead/fast way to convert a 2D array to Rust's safe objects instead?

I could not find anything directly on the topic of representing non-trivial C-types to Rust, so any material in that direction would also be very helpful.

Edit:
Every row in the array is of the same length and the size of the array is determined during the runtime.

Comment: what wrong with &mut [&mut [T]] ? slice have unsafe feature to be constructed.

Comment: @Stargateur My understanding is that this would be computationally expensive, say I have (10^9) x A elements, I'd have to iterate through all the 10^9 outer-elements to construct the inner-slices.

Comment: well, that why 2D vector are evil... you could also use directly the C pointer, not a big deal at this point. Also how do you know the size of your vector in C ? if this is the classic NULL and \0 value then again a reason to not use slice at all and use pointer "like in C".

Comment: Is this a jagged array or do all the `char *`s point to arrays of the same length? If they are the same length, is the length known at compile time?

Comment: @trentcl yes, they are of the same length and the array size is determined at run-time.

Comment: @Stargateur The rust library works with raw bytes in the memory that outlive the rust library and the driver program. The actual function in the library does not take a char array, but a pointer to an object. This object is a C-like struct that has fields for size of each dimension, other metadata and a 2d array. Since those bytes in the memory are supposed to be readable across different versions of Rust and from different languages I cannot directly use Rust's builtin types.

Comment: @Stargateur seems like directly using unsafe C pointers is the only option.